# Why Must Specializing Argument be void?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, enable-if, template-variables

So yet another question in [this saga](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56649481/2642059). [Guillaume Racicot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2104697/guillaume-racicot) has been good enough to provide me with [yet another workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56650205/2642059) so this is the code I'll be basing this question off of:

```
struct vec
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

namespace details
{
template <typename T>
using subscript_function = double(*)(const T&);

template <typename T>
constexpr double X(const T& param) { return param.x; }

template <typename T>
constexpr double Y(const T& param) { return param.y; }

template <typename T>
constexpr double Z(const T& param) { return param.z; }
}

template <typename T, typename = void>
constexpr details::subscript_function<T> my_temp[] = { &details::X<T>, &details::Y<T> };

template <typename T>
constexpr details::subscript_function<T> my_temp<T, enable_if_t<is_floating_point_v<decltype(details::X(T()))>, T>>[] = { &details::X<T>, &details::Y<T>, &details::Z<T> };


int main() {
    vec foo = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };

    for(const auto i : my_temp<decltype(foo)>) {
        cout << (*i)(foo) << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem seems to arise in my specialization when I return something *other* than `void`. In the code above for example, `enable_if_t<is_floating_point_v<decltype(details::X(T()))>, T>` prevents specialization, while simply removing the last argument and allowing `enable_if` to return `void` allows specialization.

I think this points to my misunderstanding of what is really happening here. Why must the specialized type always be `void` for this to work?

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/pYqiUS)

Answer (score 7):

Not sure to understand what you don't understand but...

If you write

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
constexpr details::subscript_function<T> my_temp[] = { &details::X<T>, &details::Y<T> };

template <typename T>
constexpr details::subscript_function<T> my_temp<T, enable_if_t<is_floating_point_v<decltype(details::X(T()))>, T>>[] = { &details::X<T>, &details::Y<T>, &details::Z<T> };
```

you have a first, main, template variable with two templates: a type and a type with a default (`void`).

The second template variable is enabled when `std::enable_if_t` is `void`.

What's happen when you write

```
for(const auto i : my_temp<decltype(foo)>)
```

?

The compiler:

1) find `my_temp<decltype(foo)>` that has a single template parameter

2) look for a matching `my_temp` template variable

3) find only a `my_temp` with two template parameters but the second has a default, so

4) decide that `my_temp<decltype(foo)>` can be only `my_temp<decltype(foo), void>` (or `my_temp<vec, void>`, if you prefer)

5) see that the main `my_temp` matches

6) see that the `my_temp` specialization doesn't matches because

```
enable_if_t<is_floating_point_v<decltype(details::X(T()))>, T>
```

is `T` (that is `vec`), so could match only `my_temp<vec, vec>` that is different from `my_temp<vec, void>`.

7) choose the only template variable available: the main one.

If you want that the specialization is enabled by

```
enable_if_t<is_floating_point_v<decltype(details::X(T()))>, T>
```

you should use `T`

```
// ..............................V   T! not void
template <typename T, typename = T>
constexpr details::subscript_function<T> my_temp[] = { &details::X<T>, &details::Y<T> };
```

as default for second template type in the main template variable.

Off Topic suggestion: better use `std::declval` inside the `std::is_floating_point_v` test; I suggest

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<decltype(details::X(std::declval<T>()))>>
```

Answer (score 2):

How template specialization works:

There is a **primary specialization**.  This one basically defines the arguments and defaults.

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
```

This is the template part of your primary specialization.  It takes one type, then another type that defaults to `void`.

This is the "interface" of your template.

```
template <typename T>
[...] <T, enable_if_t<is_floating_point_v<decltype(details::X(T()))>, T>> [...]
```

here is a **secondary specialization**.

In this case, the `template <typename T>` is fundamentally different.  In the primary specialization, it defined an interface; here, it defines "variables" that are used below.

Then we have the part where we do the pattern matching.  This is after the name of the template (variable in this case).  Reformatted for sanity:

```
<
  T,
  enable_if_t
  <
    is_floating_point_v
    <
      decltype
      (
        details::X(T())
      )
    >,
    T
  >
>
```

now we can see the structure.  There are two arguments, matching the two arguments in the primary specialization.

The first one is `T`.  Now, this matches the *name* in the primary specialization, but that means nothing.  It is like calling a function `make_point(int x, int y)` with variables `x,y` -- it could be `y,x` or `m,n` and `make_point` doesn't care.

We introduced a completely new variable `T` in this specialization.  Then we bound it to the first argument.

The second argument is complex.  Complex enough that it is in a "non-deduced context".  Typically, template specialization arguments are deduced from the arguments passed to template as defined in the primary specialization; non-deduced arguments are not.

If we do `some_template< Foo >`, matching a type `T` against `Foo` gets ... `Foo`.  Pretty easy pattern match.  Fancier pattern matches are permitted, like a specialization that takes a `T*`; this fails to match against `some_template<int>`, but matches against `some_template<int*>` with `T=int`.

Non-deduced arguments do not participate in this game.  Instead, the arguments that *do* match are plugged in, and the resulting type is generated.  And if and only if that matches the type passed to the template in that slot does the specialization match.

So lets examine what happens we pass `vec` as the first argument to `my_temp`

First we go to the primary specialization

```
template<typename T, typename=void>
my_temp
```

now `my_temp<vec>` has a default argument.  It becomes `my_temp<vec,void>`.

We then examine each *other* specialization to see if any of them match; if none do, we stay as the primary specialization.

The other specialization is:

```
template<typename T>
[...] my_temp<
  T,
  enable_if_t
  <
    is_floating_point_v
    <
      decltype
      (
        details::X(T())
      )
    >,
    T
  >
>[...]
```

with `[...]` for stuff that doesn't matter.

Ok, the first argument is bound to `T`.  Well, the first argument is `vec`, so that is easy.  We substitute:

```
template<typename T>
[...] my_temp<
  vec,
  enable_if_t
  <
    is_floating_point_v
    <
      decltype
      (
        details::X(vec())
      )
    >,
    vec
  >
>[...]
```

then evaluate:

```
template<typename T>
[...] my_temp<
  vec,
  enable_if_t
  <
    is_floating_point_v
    <
      double
    >,
    vec
  >
>[...]
```

and more:

```
template<typename T>
[...] my_temp<
  vec,
  enable_if_t
  <
    true,
    vec
  >
>[...]
```

and more:

```
template<typename T>
[...] my_temp<
  vec,
  vec
>[...]
```

ok, remember we where trying to match against `my_temp<vec,void>`.  But this specialization evaluated to `my_temp<vec,vec>`, and those don't match.  **Rejected.**

Remove the `,T` from `enable_if`, or make it `,void` (same thing), and the last line of the above argument becomes `my_temp<vec,void>` matches `my_temp<vec,void>`, and the secondary specialization is chosen over the primary one.

---

It is confusing.  The same syntax means fundamentally different things in primary specialization and secondary ones.  You have to understand pattern matching of template arguments and non-deduced contexts.

And what you usually get is someone using it like a magic black box that you copy.

The magic black box -- the patterns -- are useful because they mean you don't have to think about the details of how you got there.  But understanding pattern matching of template arguments, deduced and non-deduced contexts, and the differences between primary and secondary specializations is key to get why the black box works.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
struct vec
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

and

```
template <typename T>
constexpr double X(const T& param) { return param.x; }
```

we'll find out that

```
is_floating_point_v<decltype(details::X(T()))
```

evaluates to `true` (unless you're going to specialise `X` for `vec` not to return floating point...).

So we actually have:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr details::subscript_function<T> my_temp<T, enable_if_t<true, T>>[]
    = { /*...*/ };
```

or shorter:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr details::subscript_function<T> my_temp<T, T>[]
    = { /*...*/ };
```

(if it exists at all, of course...). Explicitly choosing one or the other:

```
my_temp<decltype(foo), void>
my_temp<decltype(foo), int>
my_temp<decltype(foo), double>
```

all match the main template, but none of the specialisation.

```
my_temp<decltype(foo), decltype(foo)>
```

now *does* match the specialisation (which exists because of `X(foo)` returning double...).

Finally back to `my_temp<decltype(foo)>` – well, only one template parameter given. Which is the type of the second one? The default parameter tells you (or better: the compiler), it is `void`. And according to above...

So if you want to match the specialisation, either this one needs `void` as type of second template parameter (as you discovered already) or you change the default in the non-specialized template to being equal to first template parameter (`typename T, typename = T`).

Actually, you could select *any* type for the default and the specialisation, as long as you choose the same for *both* (e. g. twice `int`, `std::string`, `MyVeryComplexCustomClass`, ...).