# Difference between `typename = enable_if_t<...>` and `enable_if_t<...,bool> = true`

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

Is there any difference between using `typename = enable_if_t<...>` and `enable_if_t<...,bool> = true` for SFINAE? I am asking specifically since I stumbled upon what seems like a bug: [Compiler error with a fold expression in enable_if_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978499/compiler-error-with-a-fold-expression-in-enable-if-t?noredirect=1#56978499)

So I got curious whether there is any actual difference between the two.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427667/sfinae-working-in-return-type-but-not-as-template-parameter

Comment: `typename = enable_if_t<...>` can't be used to disambiguate two functions, because both would have the same default template argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is difference. The first one doesn't work, while the second works. The reason for that is that default template parameters are not part of function signature.

By "work" I mean that the first version doesn't remove the function from the set of candidate overloads, which is usually desired goal when enable_if is used.

An example can be found here (Courtesy of @NathanOliver):
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a15a6f1d0eaff4ab

Comment: @lightxbulb it doesn't work in a sense that it doesn't remove a function from a set of overload candidates.

Comment: How does it not?  AFAIK it only doesn't work when you are trying to overload the function with multiple function templates.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have added some clarifying statement, this is exactly what I meant, and this is (at least in my experience) the very reason to use enable_if.

Comment: I think you might need to clarify it a bit more.  It works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcebab35f1368e5f) in an overloaded context.  It's only when you try and add multiple template overloads it fails like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a15a6f1d0eaff4ab)

Comment: @SergeyA I think this is a strange point of view that seems to be contradicted by the standard. See [temp.deduct]/6-8, [temp.over]/1. Deduction is considered to fail, therefore there is no candidate.

Comment: @Brian I removed my comment for now. I need to do a bit more research on this and I don't have time right now.

Answer (score 5):

There are minor differences, but both can be used for SFINAE.

`typename = enable_if_t<...>` forms doesn't allow "simple" overloads:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<cond<T>::value>>
void foo();

template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<!cond<T>::value>>
void foo(); // Error: redeclaration of same function as default are not part of signature
            // Both are just template <typename, typename> void foo()
```

`enable_if_t<cond, bool> = true` doesn't suffer of that:

```cpp
template <typename T, enable_if_t<cond<T>::value, bool> = true>
void foo();

template <typename T, enable_if_t<!cond<T>::value, bool> = true>
void foo();
```

Another issue with `typename = enable_if_t<...>` is that usage might be hijacked:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<cond<T>::value>>
void foo();

template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<cond<T>::value>>
void bar(T);


foo<int>();   // Regular usage, SFINAE occurs
bar(42);      // Regular usage, SFINAE occurs
bar<int>(42); // Possible usage, SFINAE still occurs
// But
foo<int, void>();   // No substitution fails here, so no SFINAE
bar<int, void>(42); // No substitution fails here, so no SFINAE
```